# Geschütztes Leerzeichen nach Zahl, vor adjektiv

Tags: adjective

`30 Kilogramm` kann man mit geschütztem Leerzeichen schreiben, wenn man die Zeit und die Tastaturkürzel hat. Wenn visuell `° = geschütztes Leerzeichen`, dann: `30°Kilogramm`

`30 Äpfel` auch, oder? Also: `30°Äpfel`.

Was passiert, wenn Adjektive sich einmischen? `30 rote Äpfel` oder `30°rote Äpfel`?

Comment: Es ist unklar, worauf die Frage abzielt und was das mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun hat.

Comment: Ich denke es geht hier um das, was im Deutschen als guter Stil des Buchsatzes  gilt. Insofern erachte ich das schon noch on topic

Comment: @RHa Detailfrage zum Thema geschützte Leerzeichen, verwandte Fragen siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=Gesch%C3%BCtztes+Leerzeichen

Answer (score 2):

Typographie ist ein weites Feld und kann beliebig kompliziert werden, aber der Grundgedanke ist ein relativ einfacher: der Lesefluß soll möglichst unterstützt werden. Aus diesem Grundgedanken leiten sich die meisten der "Bestimmungen" her. Behalten wir also im Hinterkopf, daß gute Typographie nicht so sehr im Einhalten von bestimmten Regeln besteht, sondern vielmehr darin, diesen Lesefluß zu fördern.

Was genau ist nun "der Lesefluß"? Das ist eine Ansammlung von physiologischen, ästhetischen, praktischen und anderen Maßgaben:

- die Seite soll angenehm auf den Betrachter wirken
- die einzelnen Zeilen und die Zeichen, aus denen sie bestehen, sollen möglichst einfach für das Auge erfaßbar und dekodierbar sein
- Der Sinn des Geschriebenen soll mit möglichst wenig Aufwand entzifferbar sein

und so weiter, und so weiter. Ich spare mir eine, den Rahmen hier sprengende, Einführung in die Kunst des Schriftsatzes, ich wollte lediglich erläutern, aus welcher Ecke das Nachstehende herrührt.

Bei Wort-Trennungen (das gilt für einzelne Wörter genauso wie für zusammengesetzte Fügungen, wie in deinem Beispiel), gibt es einige Bestimmungen, die einander durchaus zuwiderlaufen können. Die *Kunst* des Schriftsatzes besteht unter anderem auch darin, die jeweils günstigste unter mehreren problematischen Alternativen zu wählen.

- Wörter und Fügungen sollen so geteilt werden, daß die einzelnen Teile nicht übermäßig kurz werden. zB "augen-fällig", aber nicht "au-genfällig" oder "augenfäl-lig"
- Beim Blocksatz sollte darauf geachtet werden, daß - von Weitem betrachtet - ein möglichst einheitlicher "Graueindruck" des Drucks entsteht. Werden die Wortabstände satzbedingt zu groß, dann entstehen "helle Flecken" im Schriftbild. Beim Flattersatz sollten die Zeilen auch ungefähr gleich lang sein, sodaß eine optische Unterscheidung zwischen (kürzeren) Zeilen und Absatzenden möglich ist. Umbruch ist deshalb wichtig!
- Worttrennungen in aufeinanderfolgenden Zeilen sollten vermieden werden. Wenn mehrere Zeilen hintereinander mit einem Trennungsstrich enden, so sieht das häßlich aus.

Für die Beantwortung deiner Frage ist vor allem der erste Punkt wichtig: die einzelnen verbleibenden Teile sollten groß genug sein. Das bedeutet, daß manche Trennungen an Silbengrenzen (so wird das oft erklärt) besser nicht oder sogar *auf gar keinen Fall* erfolgen. Das läuft auf folgende Trennmöglichkeiten hinaus ("//" sind mögliche Trennungen):

> 30 Äpfel (keine Trennung)
> dreißig // Äpfel
> 30 rote // Äpfel
> 30 große, // runde, // rote Äpfel

Auf keinen Fall geht:

> 30 // Äpfel
> 30 Äp-//fel
> 30 // große, runde, rote Äp-//fel

und problematisch und, wenns irgendwie geht, zu vermeiden sind auch:

> 30 große, runde, rote // Äpfel
> drei-//ßig Äpfel

Answer (score 0):

Anstelle von "Äpfel" ist deine Einheit für die Zahlen "rote Äpfel". Wenn die Logik ***[Zahl]°[Einheit]*** ist, dann ist eigentlich damit alles klar.